# json_encode not returning data

Tags: php, json

I want to make an API but I'm facing problems when encoding JSON data. The database connection is correct but fetching those data as an array is also correct but I don't get those arrays as json data. Here is my code:

```
<?php
    include_once "./config.php";
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    
    header('Acess-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM post";
    
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die("Connection not found");
    
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    
        $data = [];
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        $status = true;
        $code = 1;
        
    
    }else{
    
        $data = "There is no data";
        $status = false;
        $code = 1;
    }
    
    echo json_encode(["status"=>$status,"data"=>$data,"code"=>$code]);
?>
```

*When I run this program I got nothing as output*

Comment: If you strip everything out and return hard-coded values, does it work? `$data = "Test";$status=false;$code=1;echo json_encode(["status"=>$status,"data"=>$data,"code"=>$code]);`

Comment: Acess-Control-Allow-Origin is spelt wrong, but that won't affect the output, the code looks like it should work. Can you try putting error_reporting(-1); as the first line, incase errors messages or warnings are being hidden.

Comment: If this code is producing no output at all then I would expect that it's failing.  Is error reporting on?  Have you checked the PHP logs?  What debugging have you done?

Comment: yes, when it is not found any rows from the data table that time JSON encoder works properly.

Comment: So are you getting some output or not? If not, have you checked the PHP error log?